# How to use split string to search and populate to listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

i'm a newbie in android programming.
i tried searching in the internet but i can't find any possible solution.

my program below is use to split inputted string using comma (",") 
*search from database using the split string
*populate into listview

my problem is that it only search using the last element in String Array(HERBALSUGGESSTIONSARRAY)
I want to populate all matches (SYMPTOMS2) using all the element in my String Array

for example :

user input: flu, cough

listview:
all possible illness with symptoms of "Flu" and "cough"

Sorry for my grammar guys , thanks in advance. More power Stackoverflow community

```
   searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchTexths);
   String[] HerbalSuggesstionsArray =  searchText.getText().toString().trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for(int x= 0; x<HerbalSuggesstionsArray.length;x++){

            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name,  symptoms2 FROM hsdisease WHERE symptoms2 LIKE?", 
                            new String[]{""+  HerbalSuggesstionsArray[x]} );

                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this, 
                        R.layout.herbalsuggestion_list_item, 
                        cursor, 
                        new String[] {"name", "symptoms2"},
                        new int[] {R.id.hsname, R.id.hssymptoms} );
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        searchText.getText().clear();   
        }
```

Comment: you have difficulty to use split?

Comment: split is working, my only problem is that it only gets the last element in the string array whenever i'm searching .

Comment: can you please show your splitting section in your code?

Comment: String[] HerbalSuggesstionsArray =  searchText.getText().toString().trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");

Comment: the answer you have is helping you. try to talk to the person who answered you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you query the DB and create a new adapter for every simptom.

Instead fetch the results for all symptoms at once and then create the adapter.

```
String[] HerbalSuggesstionsArray =  searchText.getText().toString().trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
String query = "SELECT _id, name, symptoms2 FROM hsdisease WHERE symptoms2 LIKE ?"

// Append as many WHERE clauses as necessary
for(int x= 0; x<HerbalSuggesstionsArray.length - 1; x++) {
    query += " OR symptoms2 LIKE ?";
}

cursor = db.rawQuery(query, HerbalSuggesstionsArray);

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.herbalsuggestion_list_item,
        cursor,
        new String[] {"name", "symptoms2"},
        new int[] {R.id.hsname, R.id.hssymptoms} );
setListAdapter(adapter);
searchText.getText().clear();
```

Comment: indeed good god, the op said that is newbie and you posted such answer without any explanation. indeed you deserve +1

Comment: Error sir: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, symptoms2 FROM hsdisease WHERE symptoms2 LIKE? OR WHERE symptoms2 LIKE ?

Comment: problem solve , thanks sir/maam i just edited some from your codes.

Comment: @MhickLucero ahh! Good that you've found the error yourself :) I'll edit my code just so no one gets errors later.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to sir/maam @user3249477

here's the working code:

```
 String[] HerbalSuggesstionsArray =  searchText.getText().toString().trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
    String query = "SELECT  _id, name, symptoms2 FROM hsdisease WHERE symptoms2 LIKE?";

    // Append as many WHERE clauses as necessary
    for(int x= 0; x<HerbalSuggesstionsArray.length - 1; x++) {
        query += " OR symptoms2 LIKE ?";
    }

    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, HerbalSuggesstionsArray);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.herbalsuggestion_list_item,
            cursor,
            new String[] {"name", "symptoms2"},
            new int[] {R.id.hsname, R.id.hssymptoms} );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    searchText.getText().clear();
```

Comment: plz have some explanation